# I'm having trouble with controlling visibility of nav drawer item from another activity using switch

Tags: android, methods, navigation-drawer

HI I want to set the visibility of an item of nav drawer visible when I go to settings from nav drawer and turn on the switch in the settings.

Here is the screenshot:

[image: Here is the ScreenShot.]

I want to visible app manager under the settings in advanced but only when I turn the switch on from settings activity.

Here is the method I m calling from settings of mainactivity to visible the item.

```
public void app_manager() {
  nav_Menu  = navigationView.getMenu();
  MenuItem item =  nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.app_manager);
  item.setVisible(true);
}
```

settings.java:

```
 MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
 mainActivity.app_manager();
```

Will be thankfull for any help.

here is the logcat:

```
 Process:com.example.lenovo.connectiontest, PID: 3611
                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Menu android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.getMenu()' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at com.example.lenovo.connectiontest.Activity.MainActivity.app_manager(MainActivity.java:205)
```

Comment: You can't create an object of an activity and expect it to modify its contents. Android doesn't work that way

Comment: then how can i get my solution @SamuelRobert

Comment: What is Settings.java file? Is it another activity?

Comment: yes it's another activity in which I have only switch to turn on the visibility of an item of nav drawer @SamuelRobert

Comment: when I am using it this way

Comment: MainActivity mainactivity;    mainacitvity.app_manager(); it's still crashing.

Comment: Start Settings `startActivityForResult()` and override `onActivityResult` method to handle the result from Settings activity

Answer (score 0):

Navigation Drawer view contains a Listview or Recyclerview which has an adapter. You have to notify the adapter after update any UI component in Navigation Drawer items.

If you want to create a custom Navigation Drawer, you should follow these steps:

1. Create a boolean field named 'isVisible' in your Navigation Drawer model(ex: MenuItem).
2. When you change 'isVisible' field, you have to notify the Navigation Drawer adapter.

Comment: it neither contains a listview nor a Recycler view. i m using NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener